# Bootstrap modal does not display properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a modal which should be displayed when clicked on a table row. When i am using Bootstrap 2.x it displays properly, but when using Bootstrap 3.x the modal moves in extreme left of laptop display and is only viewed half. I am not good at designing, can someplease help me with this issue.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="monitor-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    </div>


$("#tableId").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    $("#tableId").find("tr.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    columns = e.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("td");
    isSelectedMachineVacant = columns[columns.length-1].childNodes[0].className.indexOf("label-success") > -1

    if (isSelectedMachineVacant) {
        $("#temp").val("");
        $("#fan-val").val("");
        $("#heater-val").val("");
        $("#test-modal").modal();
    }
    else {
        $("#monitor-modal").modal();
        getLogs();
    }
});
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with python and django. You should remove them from tags

Comment: Please make a snippet so that we could launch and find the issue out faster

Comment: https://codepen.io/CruiseDevice/pen/WayBOO?editors=1010

Comment: Do you your modal to be displayed on the center of the page?Because in your codepen you don't have jquery enabled.

Comment: I think i have enabled Jquery in the pen.

Comment: If you're upgraded from an earlier version of Bootstrap, it might be worth taking the plunge and moving to Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Part of my project was using Bootstrap 2 and the other was using Bootstrap 3. Replacing Bootstrap 2 by 3 completely solved the problem. Now the modal displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you to create a modal that displays in the right way https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp.

Also explains everything step by step.

Example code of a simple modal using the bootstrap 3 documentation

Also you have to import jquery and bootstrap.js preferably in the footer

```
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO as links go dead or change over time. However, you can use that information to compliment and form your own answer. If you can't do that, you should delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer